# Gradle get current dependency version

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to create an task that deletes all the old versions of my dependency, I got it working but the problem is to my dependency version has '.+' in version for build number, so when I get it all the folders get deleted instead of only the older ones. I currently have this:

```
task cleanTerraCore(type: Delete) {
doLast {
    def dirName = new File("${gradle.gradleUserHomeDir}/caches/minecraft/deobfedDeps/deobf/terrails/terracore/TerraCore")
    dirName.eachDir { dir ->
        project.configurations.deobfCompile.dependencies.each {
            System.out.println(it.version)
            if (dir.name.contains("SNAPSHOT") && it.name.contains("TerraCore")) {
                if (!dir.name.contains(it.version)) {
                    delete(dir)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   deobfCompile("terrails.terracore:TerraCore:" + getMajorMC() + "-" + "${terracore_version}-SNAPSHOT.+")
}
```

'it.version' always prints out 'SNAPSHOT.+' so I'm not sure how to handle this, could I somehow efficiently check for the biggest build number?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after couple of hours. It now gets the latest version without the '+' symbol

```
task cleanTerra(type: Delete) {
doLast {
    def dirName = new File("${gradle.gradleUserHomeDir}/caches/minecraft/deobfedDeps/deobf/terrails/terracore/TerraCore")
    dirName.eachDir { dir ->
        configurations.deobfCompile.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.each {
            System.out.println(it.moduleVersion + ", ${it.moduleName}")
            if (dir.name.contains("SNAPSHOT") && it.moduleName.contains("TerraCore")) {
                if (!dir.name.contains(it.moduleVersion)) {
                    delete(dir)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So the println now prints out the full version (currently "1.12-2.1.10-SNAPSHOT.7") and the name of the dependency "TerraCore"